# Elmah sends too many error mail

Tags: asp.net, email, webforms, smtp, elmah

I install elmah in my asp.net webforms project. When i type
    `http: //mylocalhost/application/asdfasdfasdfasdfsdf` (wrong url) 
It logged error and send mail. But send too many mail. I got 1 error and it send 10 (may be 20) error mail. I don't know why.

Comment: I think you must bring here settings. And think about buffering errors because one mail for one error really spam you.

Comment: I releazed that..I got too many mail because my web site has too many error. Elmah send css and javascript error too. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I releazed that..I got too many mail because my web site has too many error. Elmah send css and javascript error too. Thanks for help.